# Reload macOS Photos location metadata

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a macOS Photos extension where I update the metadata for the photo. The metadata (location information) is saved correctly, but the Photos application does not recognise the changes since it seems like it is storing its own location information about the photos separately from the photo itself. If I manually export the photo from Photos and re-import it, the location is properly shown in Photos.

Is there a way (in Swift) to trigger a reload of the metadata or to re-import the photo into Photos?